# setBackground in onCreateDrawableState

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a situation where I need to setBackground of my custom button based on a condition dynamically in onCreateDrawableState.
So my code is like this

```
public class MyButton extends Button  {
public boolean nightMode = false;
private Drawable dayBackground, nightBackgound;
public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.QITheme,
            0, 0);

    try {
        dayBackground = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.MyTheme_dayBackground);
        nightBackgound = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.MyTheme_nightBackground);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

}
@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    int[] state = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace+1);
    if (CurrentThemeManager.isNightMode()) {
        if(nightBackgound != null)
            setBackground(nightBackgound);
    } else {
        if(dayBackground != null)
            setBackground(dayBackground);
    }
    return state;
}
```

}

But since setBackground calls onCreateDrawableState indirectly, I am getting StackOverflowError due to infinite recursive calls

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at android.view.ViewGroup.onCreateDrawableState(ViewGroup.java:5370)
        at android.view.View.onCreateDrawableState(View.java:14635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.onCreateDrawableState(ViewGroup.java:5370)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:69)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14611)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:14837)
        at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:14777)
        at my.mytheme.widget.MyButton.onCreateDrawableState(MyButton.java:76
```

Can someone help me fix this StackOverflowError?

Comment: In that if-else clause you need an additional boolean flag to make the system return to onCreateDrawableState() only once otherwise you'll set the background -> onCreateDrawableState() is called again -> you set the background -> etc (I'm also not sure why you absolutely need to set the drawable right there). Also, android has a night resource identifier, are you sure that isn't what you;re looking for? Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html for the night identifiers.

Comment: why do you need onCreateDrawableState?

Comment: Thank you @Luksprog . That solves the problem. And in fact I am trying to achieve day night theme change and the link you provided seems interesting. Can you provide any examples or tutorials for night implementation

Comment: @pskink I am trying to achieve day night theme switcher. I am following this http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/runtime-theme-change/

Comment: The night qualifiers are for automatic resource handling from the system: if the system sees there's a change in night/day it will reload the views to use the resources from those qualifiers. If you want to do it programmatically(which is what you want right?) then those can't help you. Instead you should do it on your own when you change the theme, this means traversing the view hierarchy and calling setBackground() on the views with the new value.

Answer (score 3):

you should not call `setBackground` from `onCreateDrawableState`. it's lazy way. but instead should change *state* from drawable.

cook it like this:

1. define your drawables in selector (e.g. with state_checked)

```
<item android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/night_image" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/day_image" />
```

2. add state handling in your custom view

   ```
   class YourFancyView extends SomeView implement Checkable {

       private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
               android.R.attr.state_checked
       };

       @Override
           protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
               final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);

               if (isChecked()) {
                   mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
               }
               return drawableState;
           }

   @Override
   public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
       if(mChecked != checked) {
           mChecked = checked;
           refreshDrawableState();

       }
   }
   ```
3. Next step - to code any resonable way to set `checked` status.

   YourFancyView v = new YourFancyView();
   if(itIsTime) v.setChecked(true);

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will actually fix the problem you're having but I think you should replace setBackground() with setBackgroundDrawable()

Comment: Even if it doesn't fix the problem I think you should keep it on setBackgroundDrawable() because you are giving the background a new drawable. I will continue to look for the answer

Comment: Thank you. But setBackgroundDrawable() is a deprecated method

Comment: You can still use it from the support library.